# Django ManyToMany in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=50L, blank=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    ...
class Group(models.Model):
    device = models.ManyToManyField(Device)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Device table contains more than 30000 records and a group can hold 5000, 10000 and more devices.

I need to:

1. Add a device to a group;
2. Viewing the contents of a group;
3. Editing the whole group (remove device).

Standard tools (`filter_horizontal`, Inline, `raw_id_fields`) are not appropriate. Because the form editing `Group` works very slowly, as it retrieves all the device records. To select the required device, needs more information (model, manufacturer, location, etc.). To remove the required device from the group, i have to  scroll through the list of 30000 devices or scroll 7000 device in group and delete it using CTRL key . This way  is not applicable.

Problem of adding devices to a group I solved by adding a custom action to the device (using the `list_filter` and `search_fields` I get the right result, then action "Add to Group")

The remaining issues I haven't found.

I want to solve the problem this way:
The user enters the Group and sees the group titles. When he clicks on the name of the group he get a list of devices  belonging to the group as a table with all device fields.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: don't use the admin site.

long answer: 
The admin site is great. It's powerful and neat and easy to configure in a few minutes. But that's about it. And that's fine, because it's not meant to be used for highly costumized projects. Yes, there are some built in ways to create costum forms for the admin site to use instead of the default, or show it in different ways, but it's still not that flexible

The way I see it, you have two options:

1. Copy the admin site files to your project, learn how it works and costumize it to your needs
2. Don't use the admin site, build your own views.

Now you might seem to like the first idea, but in my experience the second one is always easier. As tempting as it is to use the admin site, it's not that complicated to built something like that yourself. Here's a general explanation of how that would look:

```
url('^myadmin/$', 'myapp.views.main_admin'),
url('^myadmin/(?P<group_pk>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.admin_devices')
```

Then you have 'main_admin' show a list of groups, and 'admin_devices' would show a list of devices and their information in a table:

views.py

```
def admin_devices(request, group_pk)
    group = Group.objects.get(group_pk)
    devices = group.device.all()

    return render_to_response('devices.html', {'devices': devices})
```

template

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>device name</th>
    <th>host name</th>
    <th>ip</th>
    ... and so on...
<tr>
{% for device in devices %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ device.device_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ device.host_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ device.ip }}</td>
                    .... and so on...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

It would look way better than the admin site default look, because you can give each group some image or give a nice UI for all links for the groups, and when you see the device you could avoid loading all 30K devices, and add pagination and some themeing. There are plenty of jQuery packages around that allow easy implementaion of all the things the admin site allows for: column sorting (Datatables) or easy date adding (jQuery UI) and even in-place editing (jEditable) that would make it even easier for your users

Comment: I was afraid of this response: "don't use the admin site."
I'm not a web programmer and had no plans to deeply dive into css and java scripting. But it seems there is no other way.
Thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: Sure thing. If you don't want to "dive in" to web development then maybe django is not the tool for you. Sounds like what you really wan't is a cms (content managment system) though I doubt you'd find anything that allows this kind of customization you need.  There's never a better way than to just learn to and do things yourself (also, I strongly recommend you avoid javascript and skip straight to jQuery)

Comment: Hmm, maybe I do not renounce the use of the administrator site. 
I can override the url to show group:
url (r ' ^ admin/mcs/group/\d+', views.my_group)
url (r ' ^ admin/', include (admin.site.urls))
and write own template, view and form

Comment: You can probably find a way to use the admin site, but like I mentioned, in my experience it was always (maybe counter-intuitivley) more difficult than simply writing the views from scratch

Comment: Unfortunately I have very little time to implement the required functionality in this project.
I will definitely take your advice in the other, a personal project where I have enough time